# WP_Query tax_query multiple taxonomies and terms

Tags: php, wordpress, post, custom-post-type, taxonomy

I'm having a bit of trouble returning posts with multiple taxonomies and terms. Hoping someone with far more knowledge than myself can help me understand.

I'm using a select menu to populate the select options with taxonomy information of a page (in this case, the Products page). All is good with a single taxonomy and term in the tax_query but as soon as I try to use an array to pass multiples, i'm no longer returning anything. This seems simple enough but I'm missing something. Any ideas?

Here is what I'm working with:

```
$producttype = $_GET['ProductType'];
$businessunit = $_GET['BusinessUnit'];
$products = new WP_Query( array( 
  'post_type' => 'products',
  'posts_per_page' => 15,
  'orderby' => 'title',
  'order'   => 'ASC',
  'paged' => $paged,
  'tax_query' => array(
    'relation' => 'OR',
     array(
       'taxonomy' => 'producttype',
       'field' => 'name',
       'term' => $producttype
     ),
     array(
       'taxonomy' => 'businessunit',
       'field' => 'name',
       'term' => $businessunit
     )
  )
)
```

Comment: $producttype is an array ? and same $businessunit ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You error is a key array tax_query =>  `term` should be `terms`

```
$producttype = $_GET['ProductType'];
$businessunit = $_GET['BusinessUnit'];
$products = new WP_Query( array( 
  'post_type' => 'products',
  'posts_per_page' => 15,
  'orderby' => 'title',
  'order'   => 'ASC',
  'paged' => $paged,
  'tax_query' => array(
    'relation' => 'OR',
     array(
       'taxonomy' => 'producttype',
       'field' => 'name',
       'terms' => $producttype
     ),
     array(
       'taxonomy' => 'businessunit',
       'field' => 'name',
       'terms' => $businessunit
     )
  )
```

Reference [wordpress](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query)

Comment: Good catch, Guillermo! That's what I get for using notepad. However, I've fixed my typo and it is returning results now but it's still not returning the correct results. It seems the second item in the array is being ignored.

Comment: Nope. This is correct. You're right. I needed to use the AND operator rather than OR. All good. Thank you!